# How to export Images from web server to cloudinary

Tags: cloudinary

I have more then thousand images stored in my web server. Now I want to transfer my all store images from my web server to cloudinary . I mean ,I want to export all my images from my web server and store all  images to my cloudinary account.

Is there any possible way??How I can export the images from web server to cloudinary??

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk upload your images to Cloudinary by using:

- Using a script that goes over all the images and uploads them one-by-one. for example: `Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("sample.jpg")`
- Use Fetch to get the images. You can read about it here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images
- Use auto upload. you can read more information about it here:
  https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images#auto_upload_remote_resources

Here is a blog about it:
https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_migrate_all_your_images_to_the_cloud

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io)
They have both the options available - you can [attach your web server](https://imagekit.io/blog/optimize-images-nginx-apache-webserver-imagekit/) with it and start delivering optimized images instantly or you can get in touch with the team which will help you move your storage to ImageKit's media library.

Disclaimer : I am the founder of ImageKit.io